# how to get currently selected month

Tags: vue.js, npm, installation, vuetify.js, vcalendar

i use this lib npm install v-calendar@next @popperjs/core
and i don't know how to get the value

i want current value selected to show information of the month

````
//.
//.
//.
//.
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            initialPage: ref([{ month: new Date().getMonth() + 1, year: new Date().getFullYear() }]),
            attributes: ref([
                {
                    dot: {
                        style: {
                            backgroundColor: '#DD2C00',
                        },
                    },
                    dates: [
                        // new Date(2023, 9, 12),
                        // new Date(2023, 3, 26),
                        // new Date(2023, 5, 15),
                        // new Date(2023, 6, 15),
                    ],
                },
            ]).
//.
//.```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <DatePicker  v-model="workingDate" @update:modelValue="newDate"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```
const workingDate = ref(props.date);    
function newDate() {
     emit("newDate",workingDate.value);
}
```

Perhaps you need to show more of your code to show what you tried.
But many thanks for alerting me to this plugin - I was using [Vuetify  Labs datepicker](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/) before and it was giving me problems. This looks better.

Sorry, I'm using the Vue compostion API, you'll need to adjust my script for your case

Comment: thx for solution so if i use this https://vcalendar.io/

Comment: yes all the info you need is on that link. If you found my answer useful, please upvote it and/or mark it as correct